# Is there a way to prioritize Ruby order columns?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an order clause on a model:

```
sorted = Teacher.order('teachers.first_name asc, teachers.last_name asc')
```

And several `scope` `where` methods called on `sorted` afterwards.

Lastly, order is called on `sorted` if a sort parameter is present.

The SQL statement built by Rails would have an `order by` 3 columns, (`first_name`, `last_name` and the last one coming from `the param sent from the filters`). 
The data set would never get to be ordered by the desired column, unless there were teachers with the same `first and last name`.

Is there a way to prioritize the order column if the sorting parameter is present?

Comment: _"And several [...] methods [...] afterwards"_ – could you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

> Lastly, order is called on `sorted` if a sort parameter is present.

I assume it looks somehow like this:

```
sorted = Teacher.order('teachers.first_name asc, teachers.last_name asc')
# ...
sorted = sorted.order(sort_param) if sort_param
```

> Is there a way to prioritize the order column if the sorting parameter is present?

Just reorder your method calls accordingly:

```
sorted = Teacher.all
# ...
sorted = sorted.order(sort_param) if sort_param
sorted = sorted.order('teachers.first_name asc, teachers.last_name asc')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could call [`reorder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) on the relation if the parameter is present, but then you'd have to specify all the fields over again, so not very attractive.

> Replaces any existing order defined on the relation with the specified order
>
> ```
> User.order('email DESC').reorder('id ASC') # generated SQL has 'ORDER BY id ASC'
> ```

Nothing as far as I'm aware allows you to say "I want this `order` value to appear *before* the previously set `order` values"